# Calculate the Euler characteristic of a manifold equipped with a torus action

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose that $S^1$ acts freely on a manifold M. What is the Euler characteristic of $M$?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In fact, the Euler characteristic of $M$ will be $0$ even if $M$ is neither orientable nor closed.

To see this, let $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq S^1$ be the $n$th roots of unity.  The action of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is still free and so $M\rightarrow M/(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is an $n-$fold cover.

But Euler characteristic is multiplicative with respect to covers, so $\chi(M) = n\cdot\chi(M(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$, so $n\mid \chi(M)$ for all $n$.  This implies $\chi(M) = 0$.

Answer (score 6):

The Euler characteristic of $M$ will be $0$ (at least for a closed orientable manifold, but probably more generally).  One way to see this is to note that the $S^1$ action induces a nowhere vanishing vector field on $M$.

Comment: Doesn't this require that $M$ and the action be smooth?

Comment: Yes, $S^1$ acts on $M$ smoothly